# Factor $x^{35}+x^{19}+x^{17}-x^2+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I tried to factor $x^{35}+x^{19}+x^{17}-x^2+1$ and I can see that $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are two conjugate roots of $x^{35}+x^{19}+x^{17}-x^2+1$. So I divide it by $x^2+x+1$ and the factorization comes to the following

$$(x^2+x+1)(x^{33}-x^{32}+x^{30}-x^{29}+x^{27}-x^{26}+x^{24}-x^{23}+x^{21}-x^{20}+x^{18}-x^{16}+2x^{15}-x^{14}-x^{13}+2x^{12}-x^{11}-x^{10}+2x^{9}-x^{8}-x^{7}+2x^6-x^5-x^4+2x^3-x^2-x+1)$$

I couldn't go further. My question is is it end here or there is a simple way to do further?

Comment: By $\omega$, do you mean a primitive cube root of $1$?

Comment: Mathematica factors that degree 33 polynomial as a product of $1-x+x^{18}$ and a degree 15 polynomial I don't want to reproduce here. It doesn't look cyclotomic so I have no idea how to find it "by hand". I don't see easy factorizations modulo small primes (particularly modulo two) either.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen However, $p_{15}(X)\cdot X-1$ allows a somewhat nice factorization - perhaps this hints to a possible trick?

Comment: To be explicit, $p_{15}x-1= (x^6 + x^3 + 1)(x^6 - x^3 + 1)(x^2 - x + 1)(x + 1)(x - 1)$. I don't see why to bother about possible tricks. Where is the motivation for this polynomial of degree $35$?

Comment: @Arthur yes, sir $\omega ^3=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if we simply add and then subtract $x^{18}$ and x this factorization becomes easier.
$x^{35} + x^{19} + x^{17} - x^{2} +1 = x^{35}- x^{18}+ x^{17}+ x^{19}- x^{2}+x+ x^{18}- x+ 1$ = $x^{17}(x^{18}-x+1)+ x(x^{18}-x +1)+(x^{18}- x +1)$= $(x^{18}-x+1)(x^{17}+x+1)$. 
Now it is easy to see that omega is a root of $x^{17}+x+1$ which means $x^{2}+x+1$ is a factor of $x^{17}+x+1$. Now applying *vanishing method* on $x^{17}+x+1$ we easily get 
$x^{17}+x+1$ = $(x^{2}+x+1)(x^{15}-x^{14}+x^{12}-x^{11}+x^{9}-x^{8}+x^{6}-x^{5}+x^{3}-x^{2}+1$).So our required solution is
 $x^{35}+x^{19}+x^{17}-x^{2}+1=(x^{18}-x+1)(x^{2}+x+1)(x^{15}-x^{14}+x^{12}-x^{11}+x^{9}-x^{8}+x^{6}-x^{5}+x^{3}-x^{2}+1)$

Comment: Nice! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Can one find the factors by hand? Well, *perhaps* with a bit of guessing.

---

In the big factor
$$\begin{align}p_{33}(x)&=x^{33}-x^{32}\\&+x^{30}-x^{29}\\&+x^{27}-x^{26}\\&+x^{24}-x^{23}\\&+x^{21}-x^{20}\\&+x^{18}\\&-x^{16}+2x^{15}-x^{14}\\&-x^{13}+2x^{12}-x^{11}\\&-x^{10}+2x^{9}-x^{8}\\&-x^{7}+2x^6-x^5\\&-x^4+2x^3-x^2\\&-x+1,\end{align}$$
you may notice a pattern that is *almost* perfect, namely we *almost* always can group the monomials as $x^{n+1}-x^n$  (or, in particular in lower degrees, as $x^{n+2}-2x^{n+1}+x^n=(x^{n+2}-x^{n+1})-(x^{n+1}-x^n)$.
Only $x^{18}$ does not fit into this. And if we want to insist on the $x^{n+2}-2x^{n+1}+x^n$ pattern for all low degrees, then also $-x+1$ dose not fit any more.
Thus
$$p_{33}(x)=(x^{18}-x+1)+ (x-1)\cdot x^2\cdot p_{30}(x)$$
for some degree $30$ polynomial $p_{30}$, which happens to be *nice* in that it suspiciously only has coefficients $\in\{-1,0,1\}$. Of course, such an additive composition is usually of no help to finding a factorization.
Out of despair, we check if $p_{30}$ is a multiple of the first dummand $x^{18}-x+1$ and by chance succeed:
$$\begin{align}p_{30}(x)&=x^{30} + x^{27} + x^{24} + x^{21} + x^{18} - x^{13} + x^{12} - x^{10} + x^9 - x^7 + x^6 - x^4 + x^3 - x + 1\\
&=(x^{18}-x+1)(x^{12} + x^9 + x^6 + x^3 + 1)
\end{align}$$
and that last factor is easily recognized as $\frac{x^{15}-1}{x^3-1}$, which might be considered motivational.
However, $p_{30}$ is not what we wanted to factor. Nevertheless, our pipe-dream made us arrive at
$$p_{33}(x)=(x^{18}-x+1)\cdot p_{15}(x)$$
with $$\begin{align}p_{15}(x)&=1+(x-1)x^2\frac{x^{15}-1}{x^3-1}\\&=1+x^2\frac{x^{15}-1}{x^2+x+1}
\\&=x^{15} - x^{14} + x^{12} - x^{11} + x^9 - x^8 + x^6 - x^5 + x^3 - x^2 + 1.\end{align}$$